# How to enclose titles with quotation marks through changing the .bst file?

Tags: bibtex

I want to enclose the title of articles in journal:
Replacing

> Amihud, Y., Mendelson, H.. Asset pricing and the bid-ask spread.
>   Journal of Financial Economics 1986;17:223–249.

to

> Amihud, Y., Mendelson, H.. "Asset pricing and the bid-ask spread."
>   Journal of Financial Economics 1986;17:223–249.

Now, I'm using model4-names.bst, which can be obtained from the following site([hyperlink](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/sextante/docs/trunk/LaTeX/en/ArticleForCompAndGeosciences/model4-names.bst)).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add the corresponding `bib` entry to your question, so it is easier to test solutions.

Comment: real open and close quotes should be preferred here, instead of the "undifferentiated" double quotes,

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following function:

```
FUNCTION {quote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "``" swap$ * "''" * }
  if$
}
```

Then, in the function `FUNCTION {format.title}`, change the following line from

```
{ "t" change.case$ }
```

to

```
{ "t" change.case$ quote}
```

Let me know if it works ;) .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've take the liberty of editing your answer to that double quotes rather than single quotes will be placed around the title string.