# chicago.bst How to move period inside quotation marks for the title of article citations?

Tags: bibtex, citing, chicago-style

I am formatting an article for submission, and the journal requires the use of chicago.bst. However, the journal also requires a few citation features that aren't the default in chicago.bst (as far as I can tell), and I'm trying to modify the .bst file accordingly.

One thing is that article titles need to be enclosed in quotation marks. I used this other post - [How to enclose titles with quotation marks through changing the .bst file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250045) - to do this, and the solution proposed by Arturo and Mico worked great. However, the period at the end of the title is appearing outside the quotation marks. Is there a way to further modify the .bst file to fix it so the period goes inside the quotation marks?

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[bibtex, nonblind]{apsr_submission - Copy}

\begin{document}
We also consider the implications of biased updating \citep{adida2017overcoming}.}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}
```

This shows up as:

> Adida, Claire, Jessica Gottlieb, Eric Kramon, and Gwyneth McClendon. 2017. “Overcoming or Reinforcing Coethnic Preferences? An Experiment on Information and Ethnic Voting”. *Quarterly Journal of Political Science* 12(4): 437–477

I want it to show up as:

> Adida, Claire, Jessica Gottlieb, Eric Kramon, and Gwyneth McClendon. 2017. “Overcoming or Reinforcing Coethnic Preferences? An Experiment on Information and Ethnic Voting." *Quarterly Journal of Political Science* 12(4): 437–477

Thank you!